# Create a temporary table in Redshift using a JSON string format parameter

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I have a redshift stored proc signature that look like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_filtered_results
(
    p_id smallint,
    p_filters varchar(65535), 
    rs_out REFCURSOR
)
LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

The `p_filters` is a JSON formated string.

```
[{idToFilter: 1, range:'2:2', idChildren: 4, description: 'blabla1'}, {idToFilter: 2, range:'3:5', idChildren: 3, description: 'blabla2'},
{idToFilter: 3, range:'2:6', idChildren: 2, description: 'blabla3'}]
```

I would like to be able to convert that string into a temporary table where every property is a column, and every record of the array is a row in my table with a query similar to

```
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_filter
    AS
    (
        SELECT * FROM JSON_PARSE(p_filters)
    );
```

Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Are you just trying to create a temp table with one column and one row that contains a single super type value?  Neither your stored proc nor CTAS look syntactically correct.  Can you provide some more context on what you are looking to achieve?  Where does this string (p_filters) come from?  Is the contents of the stored proc going to be the CTAS?  It might help to break the problem into parts - 1) create table from string, 2) do something with the stored proc, 3) interface to some other aspects of your solution

Comment: Thanks for you comment @BillWeiner I update my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's break this into pieces as I said before.  (

**#1 Convert the string into rows and columns**

The first issue here is that your string is not valid JSON.  JSON requires double quotes not single quotes but this is easily fixed.  However, the string is still not valid as the identifiers need to be quoted as well.  So when you have:

> [{idToFilter: 1, range:'2:2', idChildren: 4, description: 'blabla1'}, {idToFilter: 2, range:'3:5', idChildren: 3, description: 'blabla2'},
> {idToFilter: 3, range:'2:6', idChildren: 2, description: 'blabla3'}]

it really needs to be:

> [{"idToFilter": 1, "range":"2:2", "idChildren": 4, "description": "blabla1"}, {"idToFilter": 2, "range":"3:5", "idChildren": 3, "description": "blabla2"}, {"idToFilter": 3, "range":"2:6", "idChildren": 2, "description": "blabla3"}]

You'll need to fix your input string (at least the quoting of the identifiers) for this to work.

Then we need to convert the string to super and then unroll it.  The SQL for this looks like:

```
create table test as select '[{\'idToFilter\': 1, \'range\':\'2:2\', \'idChildren\': 4, \'description\': \'blabla1\'}, {\'idToFilter\': 2, \'range\':\'3:5\', \'idChildren\': 3, \'description\': \'blabla2\'},
{\'idToFilter\': 3, \'range\':\'2:6\', \'idChildren\': 2, \'description\': \'blabla3\'}]' as p_filters; 

SET enable_case_sensitive_identifier TO true;

with fix_quotes as (
select replace(p_filters,'\'','"') as p_filters from test
),
json_value as (
SELECT JSON_PARSE(p_filters) as json from fix_quotes
)
select i."idToFilter", i.range, i."idChildren", i.description 
from json_value j, j.json i;
```

The first CTE in this example is changing the quotes to double. (I manually changed the initial string to fix the missing quotes.)  The second CTE converts the value to SUPER.  The top select unrolls the super.

Also note that you'll need to change to case sensitive identifiers in your Redshift session since you have upper case characters in your json.

From here it is a matter of coding up the rest of the steps but let's see if this makes sense first.  This really is the meat of the question.  Other steps will be wrapping this query in a CTAS and putting it all in a stored proc with the passing of the input string.  These steps are straight forward but I can help if more is needed.